# Cross browser input & select height consistency

Tags: css, html, height, consistency

**Criteria**: HTML & CSS/Style;
**Demand**: Cross browser (FF, IE & GC at least) height consistency;
**Applies to**: HTML5 INPUT & SELECT elements.

**Conditions**:

a. Elements must inherit line height from the parent element (SELECT element may not be affected by the line height, but must maintain height consistency);

b. Elements must not be bind by height, meaning, they should grow/shrink by the impact of font size and line height;

c. Line height cannot be expressed in explicit units (Xpx) but in generic ratio (1, 1.5, 2, etc);

**Environment**: Elements will have their own padding with box model to border;

**My CSS reset that needs the fix**:

```
body{font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, Arial; font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.44;}
input, select, textarea{box-sizing: border-box; border: 1px Grey solid; padding: 5px; font-family: inherit; font-size: inherit; line-height: inherit; vertical-align: top;}
input::-moz-focus-inner{border: 0; padding: 0;} /* Firefox fix */
```

**Desired impact**:

a. No matter whatever font family and font size specified for the BODY element, the INPUT & SELECT elements will always remain with pixel perfect same height with major web browsers;

b. Height will always remain the same for major web browsers. Like, if FF makes the INPUT of height 24px, GC will make it 24px too, and so is with others (For IE, I don't care with backward compatibility, the Edge engine compatibility is just fine, still, if Edge has bugs, considerable enough);

**Thanks giving**: Fighting with this for hours and really need an end to this life long issue permanently. Taking StackOverflow as the last resort. Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: You can't. Every browser has their own render methods. You might get similar results, but never exact.

Comment: Note: All the elements also has "vertical-align: top;" specified.

Comment: Dear Daniel, yes, I admit that, anything closest to my imagination?

Comment: You might want to consider a CSS framework such as Bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms You can examine how they deal with the problem by inspecting the elements.

Comment: I said "investigate their methods of dealing with your problem by inspecting the input elements"